# What to do after failing the Starting Strength Novice Linear Progression

Tags: strength-training, starting-strength, novice

I've been doing LP for 4 months. I've gained 10kg in the first 3 months (from 83-93kg), rest between sets, enough sleep, no injuries, and adding weight on the bar.

I did not get weaker on any of the lifts during the progression, only on overhead press. I had 45kg x5 for 3 sets but a week later I can't even do 40kg x5.

But, I was failing later sets of squats and deadlifts during the program occasionally but would manage to recover on the next workout. Some of the fails were due to wrong form, but for some my grip was weak or I just couldn't get out of the hole or lift the bar.

I did the 4th month to try to catch up but I can't seem to progress from workout to workout (this happened on press and bench press much sooner).

My working set lifts are:
Squat - 90kg x5
Deadlift - 90kg x5
Bench press - 60kg x5
Press - 40kg x5

From what I've been reading, this is not considered good progress on the novice linear progression.

Is there a way to restart the linear progression and do it properly?

I had shoulder inflexibility that fatigued my shoulders after squats (low bar position was hard) and I feel this impacted my pressing abilities. I also have a fairly weak grip and failed the deadlift with the grip too many times. I feel like I wasted too much time trying to figure out my weaknesses.

Comment: There are lots of discussions about the program on Starting Strength forums, I recommend you to check the forums.